# Where is the Evaluate on console in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome

After I update my chrome, I cannot see the `Evaluate on console` in Chrome Developer Tools, Here is the screenshot

[image]

the chrome version is `Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

What happened? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 26):

No idea what happened, I've been missing that option too but you can use the shortcut

```
CTRL - SHIFT - E
```

Comment: It looks like you have copy and paste it in the `console` tab by yourself. Do not forget to resolve the `this` variables.

Comment: This was a useful option. Does anyone know if it was removed intentionally or if it's a bug? I've tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Still not fixed in chrome 78

Answer (score 8):

A quick workaround for "Evaluation to console":

Add selection to watch and see result in watches section or right sidebar.

[image]